# Как сделать доступным метод в сервисе?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Структура такая:

```
- app
  - services
    - add_xlsx_file.rb
  - routes.rb
  - models.rb
- helpers
  - xlsx_helpers.rb
- app.rb
```

В **app.rb**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './sinatra/xlsx_helpers'

helpers Sinatra::XlsxHelper

Dir.glob('./{app,config}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
Dir.glob('./app/services/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
```

В **routes.rb** вызывается сервис:

```
post '/clients' do
  # ...
  XlsxFile.new(client).call
end
```

В самом классе сервиса вызывается метод `#initialize_xlsx_file`. Сам метод написан в хелпере XlsxHelper.

Т.е. определен в **helpers/xlsx_helpers.rb**, вызывается в **services/add_xlsx_file.rb**

`#initialize_xlsx_file` не виден в сервисах.
Ошибка `undefined method initialize_xlsx_file` Никаких require в сервисах нет, ничего не подключал. Не от чего эти классы не наследовал.

В **routes.rb** этот метод отрабатывает хорошо.

Comment: Не очень понятно, где определен метод initialize_xlsx_file, где и как он вызывается?

Comment: определен в **helpers/xlsx_helpers.rb**, вызывается в **services/add_xlsx_file.rb**

Comment: Никаких require в сервисах нет, ничего не подключал. Не от чего эти классы не наследовал.